# harvest jquery-chosen without select?

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

Is it possible to use harvest jquery chosen without having to use the default `<select><option>abc</option></select>` markup?

I'd like to either have this kind of code transformed to a responsive harvest like chosen field:

```
<!-- Language Switcher -->
<ul>
  <li><a href="abc.com/lang/german">Switch language to german</a></li>
  <li><a href="abc.com/lang/english">Switch language to english</a></li>
</ul>
```

Or it would also be ok for me to write the html code just like the finished output that harvest chosen generates from a select tag (div with ul, li and the classes chzn-drop, chzn-results, ...). And I already tried that, but I have no idea how to kickstart chosen javascript to use that block just as it is, not to try to transform anything anymore.

The reason is: I want that language-switcher select to be SEO'ed (have links as links and not as some data-* attribute of an option that I read and only react on with javascript) while keeping the nice look and functionality of chosen-select.

**Edit**
It seems that this is not possible without modifying the plugin

Comment: At the risk of revealing an extreme ignorance, what is a "chosen select"?

Comment: yeah, it should be jquery chosen, I changed the title now, price for working after midnight

Comment: You will need to do one of two things; perform the transform or create your own version of the plugin. You can always duplicate the links, somewhere else on the page, for SEO purposes.

Comment: Are you talking about https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen ?

Comment: yes I'm talking about harvest chosen

Answer (score 0):

You Could use your own wrapper or plugin to make it acceptable for choocen
Example like:

```
<ul id="TesT">
  <li><a href="abc.com/lang/german">Switch language to german</a></li>
  <li><a href="abc.com/lang/english">Switch language to english</a></li>
</ul>
```

Small script:

```
function modi(selector){
   $(selector).each(function(){
   var html ="";
   $('li',this).each(function(){
      html +='<option value="'+$('a',this).attr('href')+'">'+$('a',this).html()+'</option>';
   });
   $(this).replaceWith('<select>'+html+'</select>').chosen();
   });
}
```

And call it like:

```
modi('#TesT');
```

At the moment my script replaces old original markup, but you could allso use hiding and adding new elements.

Comment: but in the end, I would get a select again, which I didn't want to

Comment: Then you need to write new plugin or modify choocen to meet your needs

Comment: Hooray for the `modi(selector)` part. :)